# Callback passed as object property fires twice

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, wsgi

I have a boilerplate ajax call that retrieves and renders tables from a database. I had originally passed multiple arguments, which varied. To generalize the code, I put them all into an options object. Ideally, I would like to pass the callback in the options object as well, but what I find is that when I attempt to pass the callback into the object, it executes.

See the third line below. When uncommented, it causes the callback function to fire.

```
function wsgiCallbackTableData (actionobj, callback) {
  // How I would like to pass the callback in the calling function
  //actionobj.callback=callback

  // Get the data
  actionobj.action = 'gettabledata';
  if (!actionobj.hasOwnProperty('start')){
    actionobj.start = 0;
  }
  var starttime = new Date().getTime();
  $.ajax({
    url: "/wsgireadonly",
    type: "post",
    datatype:"json",                
    data: actionobj,
    success: function(response){
        console.log('SUCCESS: ' + actionobj.tablename)
        // Execute our callback function
        response = response || {};
        var now = new Date().getTime();
        response.responsetime = now - starttime;
        if (response.hasOwnProperty('etag')){
            actionobj.etag = response.etag;
        }
        callback(response,actionobj);
    }
  });   
}
```

When I call the above using something like the code below, it works fine:

```
function GetAndRenderTableData(options){
  var callback=RenderTableData;
  wsgiCallbackTableData(options, callback)
}
```

Interestingly, if I change the name of the object and assign the callback to a random obj, e.g.

```
var arandomobj={}
arandomobj.callback=callback;
```

Everything is fine. So somehow when ajax gets the object, it fires the included function.

So how can I pass the function as an object method without it executing?

Comment: `actionobj.callback=callback`, declaring it like this shouldn't fire the function.

Comment: I agree. In fact, in the calling function as above, if I comment out wsgiCallBackTableData and insert the line options.callback = RenderTableData, it does not fire. But if I uncomment the wsgi function, it does fire.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not the `actionobj.callback=callback` that causes the execution. jQuery is doing this. I think they want to execute functions inside the `data` object to return values.

You could do this:

```
function GetAndRenderTableData(options){
   var callback= "RenderTableData";
   wsgiCallbackTableData(options, callback)
}
```

Then in the ajax success do this:

```
    if (window[actionobj.callback])
    {
       window[actionobj.callback](response,actionobj); 
    }
```

Since the functions are really properties of the window we can retrieve them by using the window object.

See my fiddle for the complete code. I changed the success handler to error, since I can not execute a xhr successfully from JSFiddle. It will fire the alert only once now.

http://jsfiddle.net/nvenj38m/

Comment: This worked; thanks! What a strange quirk. It seems as though this should be an option in the ajax query, like 'no execute'.  --C

Comment: In the end, what I ended up doing was transferring the object method to a local function in the ajax function and deleting the method from the object before passing it to ajax. I then readd it as a method. This allows me to pass anonymous functions, and not every function has to be in the global scope. It also allows my IDE to tell me when I'm trying to pass a function that doesn't exist. Regardless, this solution helped me understand why this was happening, which was the important part.